# Singularity theory references

Tags: singularity-theory, mirror-symmetry

I am looking for some good references on singularity theory. I'm interested in singularity theory in the context of mirror symmetry, so this means I'm interested in things like Picard-Lefschetz theory, oscillating integrals, Frobenius manifolds (Saito theory). I have looked at the book by Arnold, Gusein-Zade, Varchenko, and I have looked at Seidel's book, but I am wondering if there are any other good, readable, relatively introductory, not-overly-heavy-on-notation books out there. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some of the topics you are interested in are covered (very nicely) in C.Sabbah, Isomonodromic deformations and Frobenius manifolds. An introduction. A more specialised book is C.Hertling, Frobenius manifolds and moduli spaces for singularities.

Comment: Thanks. I had known about Hertling's book, but not Sabbah's book.